# Why do some people write their multi conditionals different in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

Ok so a quick example of how I would write a conditional:

```
if( a.val().length < 9 && b.val().length == 8 && c.val.length <=5 ){
// Do Something
}
```

Now someone people do this and i'm very curious as to why.

```
 if( (a.val().length < 9) && (b.val().length == 8) && (c.val.length <=5) ){
    // Do Something
    }
```

They wrap a parenthesis during each condition. I do not understand why people do this at all. Does it have a purpose or does it just have the same results as the way I write them?

Comment: It's just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Making code more readable in some way...

Comment: someone also writes `((a.val().length < 9) && (b.val().length == 8) && (c.val.length <=5)) && (function(){ // do something })();`, it's just matter of readability. The example i posted doesn't provide a great readability, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes reader clear and easier to understand. There's no meaning here for parentheses.

Notice: parentheses are used for separating the group of conditions.

Answer (score 2):

As others say its style/readability.
I frequently go one step further with extra whitespace:

```
if( (a.val().length < 9)
 && (b.val().length == 8)
 && (c.val.length <=5) ){
  // Do Something
}
```

Comment: I see ok just all for readability purposes. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The use of parenthesis may seem unecessary while there's only AND operators, but it makes the sentence more readable when you have a more complex conditional:

```
if (condition1 || condition2 && condition3 || condition4) {}
```

Becomes much more easy to understand when written like this:

```
if (condition1 || (condition2 && condition3) || condition4) {}
```

Some may include the parenthesis in both (simple and complex) cases to keep the code style.

Answer (score 1):

Different programmers have different coding styles. The first example is slightly faster to type, the second more readable. The parentheses in the second example are implied in the first (i.e. the compiler reads both the same way). The second example may take a slightly longer time to compile (not noticeable). [This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238786/does-c-compiler-remove-optimize-useless-parentheses) may help you further.